# changing ROOT_URL for meteor app

Tags: meteor

I am trying to get my app to run behind an NGINX reverse proxy and had some minor success.

the path is `http://dev.sertal.ch/myApp` and the application is accessible.

The issue I am still facing is that the images in the `public` folder are not accessible without hard coding  `myApp` at the start of the URL. This is especially an issue for URLs inside the CSS.

Comment: Are you setting the evironment variable ROOT_URL to 'http://dev.sertal.ch/myApp'?  Mentioned in [doc here](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_absoluteurl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to set the ROOT_URL environment variable when you start your meteor app.  If you are using `meteor` to start from the command line in your app's directory it would be like this:

```
ROOT_URL=http://dev.sertal.ch/myApp meteor
```

Comment: This can be set by default in a conf file in order to avoid to type the root_url everytime? Maybe using http://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-settings ?

Answer (score 1):

Meteor has a ROOT_URL property which you must explicitly set for your bundled applications.

It is in the form of `Meteor.absoluteUrl([path], [options])` and the `path` argument is exactly what you're looking for, excerpt from the docs:

> A path to append to the root URL. Do not include a leading "/".

Check here for details on options http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_absoluteurl